# How can i get MR images for .dat file?

Tags: python, image, matlab

I've tried many ways for solving my problem but it doesn't work. I study neural network algorithms for detection tissue tumor and i was given a .dat file with mri images, but i couldn't open it (Other programs, online convertors etc.). Maybe has it require other options in this case? i've attached a Google Disk link with file! https://drive.google.com/file/d/12VTZkW_WEhE2v_Xzw8SY0Evst0KM6AVN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried Python package: [rawdatarinator](https://pypi.org/project/rawdatarinator/) and MATLAB code: [Gannet2.0](https://github.com/cjohnevans/Gannet2.0), but no luck... (it's start reading the file, but fails). Note: I have no experience with MRI data.